# Controlling finger reaction

Tags: guitar, fingering, fretboard

This is a follow up question of [Guitar Muscle memory lesson plan for fine motor skill deficit](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116434/guitar-muscle-memory-lesson-plan-for-fine-motor-skill-deficit)

While melodies get longer, I'm confusing, and especially if finger path are crosssing itself a lot such as

E7 - E10 - E12 - E9

I'm almost inevitably messing it up like

E7 - E9 - E12 - E10 et cetera.

or say a simple melody

E3 - E7 - E5

I'm often playing it like

E3 - E7 - E3 or
E5 - E7 - E5 etc.

Are there specific exercise or methods to clear up this type of problems??

**Update**: @Tim wrote "there is often no need to move up or down a string 3 or 4 frets" however I try to play this style of guitar

and  I follow her channel. **I use the same technique**  Is it wrong method to play?

Comment: See my answer to your last question - it's a matter of adapting that idea. There's often no need to move up or down one string more than three or four frets, that's because the guitar is designed for those of us humans with four fingers!

Comment: Try to sing or hum the melody while you're playing it. This helps to map a tone to a finger movement in your brain.

Comment: @Tim see update on my question.

Comment: @flappix make it an answer

Comment: On your update. That's hardly muscal guitar playing. It's how some of my students play when they start with me. Sorry, but that sounds very, very amateur, and certainly won't align with what I include in my answer. If nothing else, the phrasing cannot be played effectively. There must be a thousand better channels to follow.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. So its amateurish but not "wrong" okey?? or it is technically wrong?

Comment: 'Wrong' is rather subjective. But if my students ended up playing like that, I'd pack up immediately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practice everything so slowly that there is no way you can play it wrong (if necessary **extremely** slowly). Then increase the speed so gradually that you still play it correctly every time. If you make a mistake slow down again.